# Error CS1061: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6) to set up Application Insights for ASP.NET Core applications

I am able to get a build in local, but when I try to run a build in my azure pipeline it fails giving me these errors :-
[image]
Here is my code :-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string[]? initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
        

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<PostgreSQLContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(sqlConnectionString));

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IWebHostEnvironment>(_webHostEnvironment);
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SystemTextJsonValidationMetadataProvider());
        });

        services.AddTransient<CustomJwtBearerHandler>();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtBearerHandler>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });
        
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.MaxModelValidationErrors = 50;
            options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
                _ => "The field is required.");
        });}
```

Comment: You're probably missing the `using` statement which makes the extension method available. I think this should be `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. IntelliSense usually has an option to add that automatically.

Comment: well i used the using statement too, but it shows as an unused  import , so i removed it.
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

Comment: Maybe add that back in. Not unlikely that the IDE just didn't realize the import was used (caching issue etc.). Have you tried to compile the project with the CLI using `dotnet build`? Could also be that you first need to restore the solution once, so the NuGet package is actually downloaded.

Comment: yes, compilation happens with dotnet build in my azure pipeline after restore

Comment: @Mushroomator added the necessary using statements but it didn't resolve the build failure